# remove all characters aside from the decimal numbers immediately followed by the £ sign

Tags: python, regex

I have text with values like:

```
this is a value £28.99 (0.28/ml)
```

I want to remove everything to return the price only so it returns:

```
£28.99
```

there could be any number of digits between the £ and .

I *think*

```
r"£[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}"
```

matches the pattern I want to keep but i'm unsure on how to remove everything else and keep the pattern instead of replacing the pattern like in usual re.sub() cases.

Comment: Use `re.findall(pattern, s)` or `re.search(pattern, s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to remove everything to return the price only so it returns:

Why not trying to *extract* the proper information instead?

```
import re

s = "this is a value £28.99 (0.28/ml)"

m = re.search("£\d*(\.\d+)?",s)
if m:
   print(m.group(0))
```

to find several occurrences use `findall` or `finditer` instead of `search`

Answer (score 2):

You don't care how many digits are before the decimal, so using the zero-or-more matcher was correct.  However, you could just rely on the digit class (`\d`) to provide that more succinctly.

The same is true of after the decimal.  You only need two so your limiting the matches to 2 is correct.

The issue then comes in with how you actually *capture* the value.  You can use a capturing group to be sure that you only ever get the value you care about.

Complete regex:

```
(£\d*.\d{2})
```

Sample code:

```
import re
r = re.compile("(£\d*.\d{2})")
match = r.findall("this is a value £28.99 (0.28/ml)")
if match: # may bring back an empty list; check for that here
    print(match[0]) # uses the first group, and will print £28.99
```

Comment: so just print `match`, empty or not, it doesn't matter

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  It'd be in a list and that may not be desirable *to* print, but I don't disagree.

Comment: anyway, that's not the most important part. findall is a good choice

Answer (score 2):

If it's a string, you can do something like this:

```
x = "this is a value £28.99 (0.28/ml)"
x_list = x.split()
for i in x_list:
    if "£" in i: #or if i.startswith("£") Credit – Jean-François Fabre
        value=i
print(value)
>>>£28.99
```

Comment: or maybe `if i.startswith("£")`

Comment: Yep.  That works too.  :)  If that symbol gets ever gets used in an application other than money in a place other than the beginning of a number, `i.startswith` would probably actually be safer.

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
import re
t = "this is a value £28.99 (0.28/ml)"
r = re.sub(".*(£[\d.]+).*", r"\1", t)
print(r)
```

---

**Output:**

```
£28.99
```

---

[Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QOt)